# Comparing two different objects using contains(Object o) returns false, when equals(Object o) returns true

Tags: java, arraylist, equals, contains

[FIXED PROBLEM BELOW]

I have this class:

```
Class Doc() {
  private String D;

  Doc(String d) {
    D = d;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceOf String) {
      if (o.equals(D)) return true;
      else return false;
    } else return false;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    ...
  }
}
```

If I run a test, initiating a Doc() using e.g. "abc" as parameter and then use `Doc().equals("abc")` it returns true - as I would expect. If I use:

```
ArrayList docs = new ArrayList<Doc>();
Doc d = new Doc("123");
Docs.add(d);
System.out.println(docs.contains("123"));
```

it returns false, and I am quite unsure of why. I have tried adding output to the `.equals()` method to check if it is used, and it is. The code for the `hashCode()` is just some bogus (I know I should do something proper, I'm just not sure how) - but I am only ever going to use `equals()`.

I read somewhere that `equals()` also checks `hashCode()`, however; if I add a `System.out.println(".")` as first line in `hashCode()` it doesn't output anything, so it doesn't seem like it is called. My best guess is that I can't compare two Objects of different class - is this correct? Or am I overlooking something else?

---

For future reference, this problem was solved using the suggestion of @JonSkeet - code is now:

```
Class Doc() {
  private String D;
  Doc(String d) {
    D = d;
  }

  public String getD() {
    return D;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceOf Doc) {
      Doc tmp = (Doc) o;
      if (tmp.getD().equals(D)) return true;
      else return false;
    } else return false;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Here `if (o.equals(D)` is `)`missing. Is it a copy/paste error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're assuming that `contains()` will call `memberInCollection.equals(candidate)` rather than `candidate.equals(memberInCollection)`. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) goes against that:

> More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

Fundamentally, your `equals` method breaks the normal contract, because it isn't symmetric - for any non-null values of `x` and `y`, `x.equals(y) == y.equals(x)` should be true. That's *not* the case with your code:

```
new Doc("123").equals("123") // True
"123".equals(new Doc("123")) // False
```

(Additionally, your `equals` method isn't even reflexive - `x.equals(x)` will never be true if `x` is a reference to an instance of `Doc`.)

Basically, you shouldn't try to make an instance of one type equal to an instance of an unrelated type. It will always end badly. It's hard enough to make equality work nicely within a type hierarchy - but for unrelated types it's a *really* bad idea.

Comment: Thank you, that confirms my suspicion. So if I changed the `equals()` method to compare `this` to a different `Doc()` instead of a String, I suppose it should work.

Comment: Also, it could be nice to tell how can be done. For example, if is an unordered list, simply do a `while` an use a custom equals method (for example, equalsName()), or if it is an ordered list, do a binarysearch with a comparator.

Comment: @ipoga: It's not clear what you mean by "work" - I wouldn't expect your original code (`docs.contains("123")`) to ever return `true`.

Comment: @JonSkeet What I meant is creating two `Doc()` object instances and comparing them: `Doc a = new Doc("123");Doc b = new Doc("123");docs.add(a);System.out.println(docs.contains(b));`

Comment: @ipoga: Right - *that* should work with a decent `equals` implementation.